# Laravel how to sort collection by specific value and id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How to sort collections by specific name and id.
I need to sort records where the name = X should be the first in the order and the rest should be sort by id.

***product model***

```
|----|------|
| id | Name |
|----|------|
|  1 | a    |
|  2 | x    |
|  3 | b    |
|  4 | c    |
|  5 | x    |
|  6 | z    |
|----|------|
```

I tried this code but not working.

```
Product::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use collections and its method...here i am using array...

try this one...

```
$product = Product::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
$results =array_map("moveToFirst",$product);

function moveToFirst($product){
  $otherIndex = array_search('x',$product);
  if($otherIndex !== false){
      $v = $product[$otherIndex];
      unset($product[$otherIndex]);
      array_unshift($product , $v);
   }
  
  return $product;
}



|---------------------|------------------|
|          id         |        Name      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          5          |         x        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         x        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         b        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         c        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          6          |         z        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: is it advisable for a large volume of data?

Comment: btw, I'm want to sort the record using query, not a collection and not using a function to sort it.

Comment: it's sort by php array in controller

Comment: i think its good way to handle from controller because mainly logic handled by controller ... then send data to view(blade) and just show it

Comment: if you handle by jquery then you need to php array store to jquery array then same process apply but replace php function to jquery array function but its little bit complex compare to php